# Using python shell, how do I associate an image with an ImageField in a class (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model, python-imaging-library

Okay so I added a field to a model called college.

Here is the new field:

```
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logos", default="static/images.default.png")
```

So I have a few images in my media folder, but how do I associate them with certain images in the class.

Would I say `Harvard.logo = ?`

Would the ? be the image path. What exactly is the image path? Using Pillow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address of the `ImageField` type starts by `MEDIA_ROOT` path and then directory that determined in `upload_to` parameter, also on the db save path similar `upload_to_dir/file_name.ext` format.
Your `default` parameter must start with `uploat_to` value, change this similar below:

```
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logos", default="logos/images.default.png")
```

And for select an image that is related to `college` value you can override `save` method of your model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logos", default="logos/images.default.png", blank=None)
    college = models.IntegerField(choices=[(1, 'Harvard'), (2, 'MIT'), (3, 'Oxford')])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.logo is None:
            if self.college == 1:
                self.logo = 'logos/Harvard.png'
            if self.college == 2:
                self.logo = 'logos/MIT.png'
            if self.college == 3:
                self.logo = 'logos/Oxford.png'

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Notice:** These default images must already exists in `logos` directory or copy to this.